# Как выбрать с таблица N записей с наибольшими значениями определенного поля.

Tags: mysql

То есть, есть таблица с id записей и количеством их просмотров, нужно выбрать 3 самые популярные.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY `cnt` LIMIT 0,3
```

Как то так.

Comment: Спасибо, это гениально) Только нужно добавить сортировку нисходящую, а то в данном случая выборка будет за наименьшими значениями.

Comment: ORDER BY `cnt` DESC